# (Beginner Java) Main method refers to a method in a seperate class which holds arrays. How would the method in the second class be set up?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

My main method has:
 the arrays

```
String[] numbers = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"};
String[] brands= {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg"};
String[] types= {"hh", "ii", "jj", "kk", "ll", "mm", "nn"};
```

a reference to my second method (in the same package with class name Soda)

```
 Soda[] list = new Soda[numbers.length];
 list = listOfSodaCans(numbers,brands,types);
```

I know my listOfSodaCans method in my Soda class has to receive the parameters in the form of `(java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[])` 
but I can't seem to get this set up. I repeatedly get a  cannot find symbol. Does anyone have some advice on what a general structure would look like for the listOfSodaCans method?

Thank you!

@Alice- my Soda method:

```
public class Soda {

private Soda[] listOfSodaCans;


          public Soda[] getListOfSodaCans() {
           return listOfSodaCans;
       }

 public void setListOfSodaCans(Soda[] listOfSodaCans) {
       this.listOfSodaCans= listOfSodaCans;
        }

    public static Soda[] listOfSodaCans(String[] numbers, String[] brands,
            String[] types) {
        // more code
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the `listOfSodaCans` method

Comment: Because your arrays are not defined as class level variables. You need to define those arrays as class level variables. Define them outside main method.

Comment: Hi 3kings, right now all I have is this: public Soda listOfSodaCans(String[] numbers, String[] brands, String[] types){
}

Comment: Is `listOfSodaCans` a `static` method, or an instance method? If it's a static method, you could add an `import static` and your current code should work. If otherwise, you'll need an instance.

Comment: You can just use `String[]`. `java.lang.*` is automatically imported, so you don't need to fully qualify those classes

Comment: Way 1. `Soda.listOfSodaCans()`
Way 2. Create instance and call it
`Soda soda = new Soda();`
`list = soda.listOfSodaCans(numbers, brands, types);`

You can not access `listOfSodaCans()` directly, because it is in another class

Comment: @Temp You can not access `listOfSodaCans()` directly, because it is *in another class*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Soda Class**

```
 public class Soda {
    public static Soda[] listOfSodaCans(String[] numbers, String[] brands,
            String[] types) {
        // more code
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Main Class** will like that

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] numbers = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
        String[] brands = { "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg" };
        String[] types = { "hh", "ii", "jj", "kk", "ll", "mm", "nn" };

        Soda[] list = new Soda[numbers.length];
        list = Soda.listOfSodaCans(numbers, brands, types);

        // way 2, accessing by instance
        // Soda soda = new Soda();
        // list = soda.listOfSodaCans(numbers, brands, types);
    }
```

If you use way 2, you better remove `static` from `listOfSodaCans()`

Comment: Hi Alice- this is extremely helpful! (and thank you to everyone else as well!)  I am wondering just about why the class name Soda was added before listOfSodaCans. Is there a way to set this up without having to add that reference? If I remove it my program won't compile again...
      This is the line I am referring to:  list = Soda.listOfSodaCans(numbers, brands, types);

Comment: If you want to you call method which is in another class. You have two ways, 1. by creating instance 2. make that method `static` same like `Soda.listOfSodaCans()`

Comment: I have a feeling I should be creating an instance. I'm sorry I keep asking for help- but is there an example you can show me?

Comment: Thanks @Alice- I tried adding it to my Soda class, but am still getting a cannot find symbol error. I have added my changes to the Soda method to my question. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works. I use the "main" class (so only one) to simplify the code, but it shall be the same.

```
import java.io.Console;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] numbers = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"};
        String[] brands= {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg"};
        String[] types= {"hh", "ii", "jj", "kk", "ll", "mm", "nn"};

        Main m = new Main();

        m.listOfSodaCans(numbers, brands, types);
    }


    public void listOfSodaCans(String[] numbers, String[] brands, String[] types) {
        System.out.println(numbers.length);
    }

}
```